# Eclipse LogCat error associated with custom font

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, custom-font

When I launch my app I get the message "Unfortunately [app name] has stopped" on my emulator.

According to my LogCat, the problem is caused by an error on line 19.

Line 19 in MainActivity.java is part of my custom text view code.

If I completely delete my custom text view code in MainActivity.java and the associated TextView in activity_main.xml I do not get the error. Therefore, I have pinpointed that this custom text view seems to be the root of the problem.

I have tried the following troubleshooting:

- ensuring the .ttf font file is written in lower case
- ensuring the .ttf font file is actually a .tff file
- storing the .ttf font file under assets
- storing the .ttf font file under fonts subfolder in assets

I have actually been on this simple issue for days. I have read numerous threads that address what seems to be my same problem, but no simple fix seems to work.

Cheers in advance for your help

**Font file is located under assets/fonts/quicksandlight.ttf**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package [package name not displayed];

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.jdubbing.scissored.R;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customfont);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/quicksandlight.ttf");                                       
    txt.setTypeface(font); 


     Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int logoTimer = 0;
                    while(logoTimer < 5000){
                        sleep(100);
                        logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                    };
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.jdubbing.CLEARSCREEN"));
                } 

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        logoTimer.start();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/startbackground" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customfont"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:textColor="#e5e3e3"
    android:text="@string/tell" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**LogCat** Check the last five or six last lines to see the error on line 19

```
01-07 03:52:12.442: I/Process(2497): Sending signal. PID: 2497 SIG: 9
01-07 03:52:19.162: D/dalvikvm(2536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 4% free 2731K/2832K, paused 104ms, total 105ms
01-07 03:52:19.162: I/dalvikvm-heap(2536): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.312MB for 614416-byte allocation
01-07 03:52:19.232: D/dalvikvm(2536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 3331K/3436K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
01-07 03:52:19.412: D/AndroidRuntime(2536): Shutting down VM
01-07 03:52:19.412: W/dalvikvm(2536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ad4b90)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): Process: [project name not displayed], PID: 2536
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[project name not displayed]/[project name not displayed].MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.jdubbing.scissored.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-07 03:52:19.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

But your textview is in `activity_main.xml`

This

```
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

will give you `NUllPointeException`

Should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current infalted layout.

Comment: Okay, cool. I understand that I am using the wrong layout file in conjunction with the TextView text. Though, if I just change to: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); I am unable to display my splash screen first. I want to show my splash screen image for 10 seconds, then display custom text on my next screens. Do I need to code a separate setContentView for the Splash screen then the activity_main screen?

Comment: splash screen is one activity. you navigate to second activity. it also needs a layout to display

Comment: @jdubbing what does your splash screen do. some people have written blogs that splash screen is not good coz it keeps the user waiting especially if it does nothing other than displaying image

Comment: Thanks, that was an easier problem to solve. All fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong layout file in your activity, that is why your `TextView txt` is null, change `setContentView(R.layout.splash);` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Thanks, as above, this solves most of my problem. Please see my response to Raghunandan if you can assist me on the last bit.